# How to identify fully formed rectangles?

Tags: imagemagick, coordinates

I'm trying to identify the coordinates of the reactangles that are fully formed. I mean, that have 4 sides with white border line making fully box.

This is the input image I have.
[image]

In the below image I show, in yellow, the rectangles for which I'd like to get the coordinates.
[image]

In this input image there are 3 black rectangles with white border line and 1 rectangle that is all white.

My current `convert` code gives coordinates of all areas, including those white areas that generate noise for my purpose.

```sh
convert input.png \
-define connected-components:verbose=true \
-define connected-components:area-threshold=100 \
-connected-components 8 -auto-level out:null | grep "255,255,255"

  7602: 233x81+295+192 411.0,232.0 18873 srgb(255,255,255)
  31: 356x70+365+28 542.4,57.2 4602 srgb(255,255,255)
  7604: 538x510+45+273 163.1,529.1 4394 srgb(255,255,255)
  7605: 292x470+627+273 809.5,494.2 2116 srgb(255,255,255)
  1393: 149x45+785+40 860.8,60.5 2040 srgb(255,255,255)
  8449: 513x125+70+658 326.0,708.6 761 srgb(255,255,255)
  7015: 43x27+291+110 312.5,122.1 620 srgb(255,255,255)
  7599: 84x43+676+148 717.5,169.0 250 srgb(255,255,255)
```

So, my question is: is there a way to identify from the output given by `convert` command, which coordinates belong to rectangles fully formed? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of ideas spring to mind. I haven't developed them into full solutions but may do so if time permits later.

- You could maybe choose the centre of each connected component in your list as the seed point for a flood-fill with, say yellow, and then make everything not yellow black (with `-fill black +opaque yellow`) and run connected components again to see if you get a filled shape the correct area. So, for example, choosing your 4th output line:

  7604: 538x510+45+273 163.1,529.1 4394 srgb(255,255,255)

And flood filling from the centre:

```
magick outlines.png -fill yellow -floodfill +314+478 black result.png
```

[image]

Or maybe go a little further:

```
magick outlines.png -fill yellow -floodfill +314+478 black -fill black +opaque yellow result.png
```

[image]

Then run another connected components analysis and see if you get a fully yellow-filled shape detected.

- You could maybe run a Hit-or-Miss morphology, looking for [line ends](https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/morphology/#lineends) and follow them back to [T-junctions](https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/morphology/#linejunctions) and erase them to get rid of the *"overshoot"* lines that stick out beyond the ends of your rectangles.

By the way, if you are looking specifically for rectangles, you will probably be better off checking for 4-connected components rather than 8-connected as at present.

Comment: Thanks Mark for your answer. I understand that from first output of connected component I get, I'll need to run a loop and do flood-fill you suggests, then apply again `connected components` and check with an `if` condition is there is only one line containing yellow? Another doubt I have is, why do you use `+314+478` in your commands? Thanks again.

Comment: Looking at the component I mentioned with geometry `538x510+45+273`. It is 538 px wide and 510px tall with its top-left corner at +45+273. So its x-centre is at `45+538/2` which is hopefully at 314. Its y-centre is at `273+510/2` which should be 528 so, yes, my 478 is slightly adrift.

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation. I'm trying to understand and apply your logic in order to get automatically the coordinates of rectangles.